# Sketch app exporting in different sizes

Tags: export, sketch-app, workflow

I often need to export my assets in multiple sizes. The '1x' and '2x' option in Sketch simply isn't enough, as I sometimes need the same icon in let's say 200x200, 300x300 and 400x400 while the original artboard might be 800x800.

Is there a way to export the contents of an artboard at a certain size?
Scaling isn't always easy in Sketch as things like text etc don't scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use fractions in export dialog.

[image: fractions in export]

And since you can export slices (which are like bounding boxes of sorts, for export purposes), which size you can define as you want, it's easy to define a slice - based on your example - on 1000x1000 dimensions, and export it as 0.2x, 0.3x, 0.4x and 0.8x.

[image: creating slices]

Comment: Darn, now I'll need basic math skills to do my job! Thanks for the very clear explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use notation with h or w.  So if you want it 400 by 400, and it's square.  You can put 400w in the size field of export.

Comment: This was a great tip. Needed a precise height scaling down and doing it as a fraction is not easy.

Comment: Thanks! Easy as pie!